# What is the most pythonic way to remove characters from a string and create substrings?

Tags: python

Let's say we have this string: `SIC0575(1, 2)`

`SIC0575` length = 7, but it could dynamically change, so let's assume length = N

`(1, 2)` let's assume (0~9, 0~9)

I would like to create substrings from this string.

Desired result:

`val1 = SIC0575`

`val2 = 1`

`val3 = 2`

I am not familiar with Python, I would like to know which is the most elegant/pythonic way to achieve that. Is there any built-in function to do that?

What I've tried (it works, but it's not elegant at all):

```
        data = "SIC0575(1, 2)"
        aux = data.split("(")
        val1 = aux[0]
        aux2 = aux[1].split(",")
        val2 = aux2[0]
        val3 = aux2[1][:-1]
```

Comment: Yes, you can learn basic `regex` (regular expressions) and extract the three values in a single search pattern.  See basic package documentation for the needed learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regexes are your friend:

```
import re
s = "SIC0575(1, 2)"
val1, val2, val3 = re.fullmatch(r"(.*?)\((\d), (\d)\)", s).groups()
```

Comment: woah this is so elegant and cool, thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 2):

For your use case, I'd go with `index`

Get the `index` of opening parenthesis `(`, and take the first slice for `aux`, and use `ast` for `val1`, `val2`

```py
import ast

data = "SIC0575(1, 2)"
index = data.find('(')
aux = data[:index]
val1, val2 = ast.literal_eval(data[index:])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
print(aux, v1, v2)
SIC0575 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like below.

```
import re
stringEx = [_.replace(' ','') for _ in re.split('\)|\(|,',"SIC0575(1, 2)")[:-1]]
var1,var2,var3 = string[0],int(stringEx[1]),int(stringEx[2])
```

out

```
val1 = SIC0575

val2 = 1

val3 = 2
```

Comment: There's standard library in Python named `string` so it'd be better to avoid using it for variable name, just a gentle suggestion though.

Comment: hmm, never new that. Thanks for the new info, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match the strings.

```
import re

data = "SIC0575(1, 2)"
pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)\(([0-9]), ([0-9])\)')
val1, val2, val3 = pattern.match(data).groups()
print(val1, val2, val3)
```